# Neo4j server crash due to lack of memory

Tags: neo4j

I am running neo4j on a 4GB RAM windows system.When i give a query which has to return about 210900 the browser tab crashes and the same happens through the shell.I plan on expanding the dataset further so there will be more nodes in future so i need to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Not an answer but... 210K results is fairly massive for a query to return. Maybe reconsider how you're querying the database?

Comment: Neither shell nor browser are meant to handle that amount of data, just use a program do get and process the data

Comment: I tried using the neo4jrestclient on python to retrieve the data but even that is crashing saying MemoryError so any other alternatives.. ?